# How much of Korean culture questions should be allowed here?

Tags: discussion

And by culture I am implying everything related to Korea besides language (history, contemporary society, music, art,  politics, etc)

The original name of this proposal was meant to be Korean Language and Culture

It was later changed to Korean Language and Usage (based on English Language and Usage) to limit the scope to language, thinking we could vote on the proposal title after sometime, but we never got around to that

Meanwhile another proposal called Korea was created around that time, which was supposed to be for discussions about Korea's culture and society, showing that the demand for such a site is present

Later on stackexchange staffs changed the title Korean Language and so here we are now. Personally I think this site should not be only about language but other aspects of Korea as well, as it was originally envisioned.

Hence, how much of Korean culture related questions should be allowed here?

Comment: user17915, I removed the multiple polling-style answers you posted in favor of an open discussion. If you have thoughts on the issue yourself, feel free to post it as an answer, but it is generally better to **let everyone have a voice** in meta to express their own opinions rather pre-posting all sides of the conversation yourself. It's not difficult to infer what the community wants from the conversation while allowing for the possibility that there's an issue we have *not* considered. **[Polling is generally not a good substitute for discussion](http://bit.ly/1g0BO6d)**. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange is a **question and answer site**, not a discussion forum. We have to always keep this principle in mind when we post a question and answer and leave a comment.

No wonder the name was changed from Korea Language and Culture to Korea Language and Usage as discussions on cultural issues like any other social issues tend to generate only primarily opinion-based answers rather than a definitive answer with proper research and reference.

I am in favor of allowing a question like [How do you count Korean age](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/156/how-do-you-count-korean-age) as it is a topic that many non-native Korean speakers find very interesting and it could be answered definitively with proper reference. However, I am against questions that can't be answered definitively.

I'd like to hear other users' opinions.

Answer (score 2):

As long as there is sufficient interest, I am happy for us to remain a language-only-oriented site - by which I mean that I would be happy *not* to open ourselves up to questions primarily about pottery, music, contemporary politics...

...however, a lot of people interested in learning Korean will also, in the exact same situations in which they need to use the Korean language, require understanding of other cultural issues. I therefore think that **we should be open-minded to cultural questions *related to communication*** - for example, common human interactions and relationships, social norms and assumptions, etiquette, status... maybe even some aspects of history...

I do agree that SE isn't the best place for linear discussion, but there are already SE sites (such as [worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), [music](https://music.stackexchange.com/), [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/)) where many successful questions invite opinions based on expert experience, so I think we can welcome such questions here too.

Comment: Having said all that, I'd prefer a successful 'Language and Culture' site to a failing 'Language and Usage' site!